# Java - line break escape in CSV

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to export the data from database to a CSV file using below code. 
I am able to generate below result using below code but this is not the result I want

```
Wrong Result: 
    1. "abcd","123","123","test","abcd","123"
    2. "abcd12","222", "333", "testing", "abc", "ccc"
    3. "abc123", "22 : 
        sdds", "sds", "s123", "54"
```

The first two row result is correct. However, in the 3rd row, the line break occur when a special character  : appear in the 2nd cell of row 3. The result I am looking for is: Are there any suggestion I can generate below result by using below code?

```
Expected Result
1. "abcd","123","123","test","abcd","123"
2. "abcd12","222", "333", "testing", "abc", "ccc"
3. "abc123", "22 : sdds", "sds", "s123", "54"
```

Code:

```
try (Writer out = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
            CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(out, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.RFC4180.withHeader(resultSet).withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL))) {


                while(resultSet.next()) {   
                    final List<String> columnList = new LinkedList<String>();
                    rowList.add(columnList);

                     for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; ++column) 
                        {

                            printer.print(resultSet.getString(column));

                        }

                     printer.println(); 

                }
                printer.flush();
                printer.close();


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
printer.print(resultSet.getString(column));
```

with

```
printer.print(resultSet.getString(column).replace(":", "\":"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The line breaks are part of your actual data and I would question why they are there in the first place and whether you really should remove them at all. If you are sure that's what you want to do, replace

```
printer.print(resultSet.getString(column));
```

with

```
String s = resultSet.getString(column);
printer.print(s.replaceAll("[\r]\n", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Apache `common-csv` package, you could use [`withEscape`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withEscape-char-) and use a suitable escape character for columns containing characters that break the format.

Current versions [apply](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.java#L1370) the supplied escape character to LF, CR, delimiter and escape character.

```
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(out, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.RFC4180
   .withHeader(resultSet)
   .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL)
   .withEscape("\\"));
```